'docker-compose up' causing node build to fail when shifted from m1 pro to m3 pro
I have a nestjs app which I run using docker-compose up (along with a db and a redis container). My dockerfile is a standard one for node projects where I use a node@16.17 image, install packages and run the development npm script. The docker-compose.yml is as follows:
version: '3.9'
services:
    backend:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 5650:3000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            -   db
            -   redis

    db:
        platform: linux/x86_64
        image: mysql:8.0.26
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: DEFAULT
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: DEFAULT
        volumes:
            - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 33066:3306

    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
            - 6679:6379

    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        logging:
            driver: 'none'
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 8025:8025

When I was on my old M1Pro, docker-compose up worked like a charm, causing none of my containers to fail. Now, after upgrading to M3Pro, my 'backend' container builds and run but causes a node error as shown in the picture

I am clueless at this point. I assumed that there must be some architecture change in the m3 pro causing this but I didnt find any solid evidence for this online. Considering that my builds on m1 pro worked okay, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Something to note, I dug into node_modules/@css-inline/index.js and read some code. I see that the code checks the platform and os using the process api and uses that to install the relevant css-inline package, which in my case is 'css-inline-darwin-arm64'. And thus the node error over not finding the css-inline-linux-arm64-gnu. Any ideas/potential fixes? Thanks!

Also, when starting the dev script outside of any docker container (just doing an npm run start:dev on the cli) my app works perfectly.

Your backend: { volumes: } block overwrites everything in the image with what's on the host system, so you're not really using Docker's immutable images here; you've reintroduced the problem that whether the system works or not depends on what you have locally.  From the last couple of sentences, you might be injecting a MacOS library tree into a Linux container.  Does deleting those volumes: help?

@DavidMaze it did not.
